# Camel XML route testing (Advice with)

Tags: java, xml, spring, apache-camel

In my project, I have declared the XML route. I just want to test it with `adviceWith` method, but I cannot load the route builder for that XML route(s). How can I tell to the Spring test, that I want to test the XML route?

XML route definition:

```
<route xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" id="ww-inbound" streamCache="true">
    <from uri="{{ww.mail.server}}?username={{ww.mail.username}}&amp;password={{ww.mail.password}}&amp;unseen=true&amp;delay={{ww.mail.consumer.delay}}"/>
    <log message="Some entry logging"/>

    <process ref="inbound.IntegrationHeaders"/>
    <process ref="inbound.Converter"/>

    <bean ref="inbound.Translator" method="translate"/>
    <to uri="file://{{ww.incoming.fs.slug}}?fileName=${in.header.INT_MESSAGE_ID}.message.json"/>
    <removeHeaders pattern="*" excludePattern="INT_CORRELATION_ID|INT_MESSAGE_ID"/>

    <log message="Outbound AMQP Message\n
        Queue: {{amqp.main.queue}}
        Headers: ${headers}
        Sender: ${exchangeProperty.SENDER}\n
        Subject: ${exchangeProperty.MESSAGE_SUBJECT}\n
        Receivers: ${exchangeProperty.RECEIVERS}\n
        Body: ${exchangeProperty.BODY}\n
        Attachment count: ${exchangeProperty.ATTACHMENTS_COUNT}"/>
    <to pattern="InOnly" uri="rabbitmq:{{amqp.main.queue}}"/>
</route>
```

The Spring test looks like this:

```
import static org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWith.adviceWith;

class InboundRouteTests extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }

    @Test
    void doTest() throws Exception {
        RouteDefinition route = context.getRouteDefinition("rot-ww-inbound");

        adviceWith(route, context,
                new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
                    @Override
                    public void configure() throws Exception {
                        replaceFromWith("mock:newStart");
                    }
                });

        context.start();

        template.sendBody("mock:newStart", "Some text");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did is instead of extending `CamelTestSupport` I used `@CamelSpringBootTest` and `@SpringBootTest(classes = WwApplication.class)` annotations. I think this enable me to use the context of the original application with the route that I needed to use.

```
@CamelSpringBootTest
@SpringBootTest(classes = RotWwApplication.class)
@UseAdviceWith
class InboundRouteTests {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the route Id in the `adviceWith()` call:

```
adviceWith(context, "ww-inbound", builder -> {
    ...
});
```

Comment: When I tried this the compiler does not compile this. The problem is that I cannot see any route in the context. I think it could be because I don't know how to call some default RouteBuilder or something like that.

Comment: What version of Camel are you running?

Comment: I updated my answer to use lambda syntax. Might have better luck with it.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Unfortunately, this did not work. I still get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot advice route as there are no routes`.


I am running camel of version 3.11.4 and Spring boot 2.7.5. 
The problem I think is, that maybe I did not cover some context or something like that and as a result I cannot see the routes when I start the test